# How to upload large files from HTML5 form using Tornado > 4.1

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.6, tornado, large-file-upload

I'm creating an application using tornado 6.0.3 and need to upload large files using an html form. How do I stream the files, eg using the `@stream_request_body` decorator, to do this?

I have created a simple form which looks like this:

```
<form action="{{ reverse_url('upload') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% module xsrf_form_html() %}
   <input class="file" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File(s)"/>
</form>
```

which redirects to the tornado handler UploadHandler and uploads (to current working directory) the chosen files:

```py
class UploadHandler(BaseHandler):
"""Class. Handles the upload of the file."""
   def post(self):
      files = []

      try:
         files = self.request.files['filesToUpload']
      except:
         pass

      for f in files:
         file = f['filename']
         with open(file, "wb") as out:
            out.write(f['body'])
```

This works, but I need to be able to handle huge files so I can't load the files in memory. Therefore I tried to use the `@stream_request_body` decorator and I found (among others) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49411727/upload-files-with-tornado-web-stream-request-body) solution, but as soon as I add the `@stream_request_body` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1674, in _execute
    self.check_xsrf_cookie()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1516, in check_xsrf_cookie
    raise HTTPError(403, "'_xsrf' argument missing from POST")
tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden ('_xsrf' argument missing from POST)
```

I then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29932601/11298006) where it says that my tornado version doesn't support streaming multiple-parts uploads, so I (since I'm using tornado version 6.0.3) need to change my form method from **POST** to **PUT** and pass the XSRF token via an HTTP header. However, html forms don't support the **PUT** method, so I'm guessing I need to use JavaScript for this in some way, but I've not used JavaScript much and I haven't found any help on how to do this.

---

So my questions are:

1. How do I stream my files from the form using the latest version of tornado, using **PUT** and (or anything else that will work) JavaScript?
2. How to I pass the XSRF token via an HTTP header? I haven't found any actual code example on how to do this.

Thank you in advance!